# Why does to_sym behave differently?

Tags: ruby

I have two strings. They behave differently with respect to `to_sym`:

```
key = "awesome123xyz"
key.to_sym #=> :awesome123xyz

object.id #=> "589d62c016bd4d0005bccc15"
object.id.to_sym #=> :"589d62c016bd4d0005bccc15"
```

Why is `object.id.to_sym` something that looks to me like a String:

```
:"589d62c016bd4d0005bccc15"
```

instead of being a symbol like this?:

```
:589d62c016bd4d0005bccc15`
```

Comment: I cant check right now but is it because it starts with an integer? Not sure symbols can start with them

Comment: @maxple please avoid leaving “I-guess-style” comments. Unless you are sure, just keep a silence, please.

Comment: @maxple: Yes, `Symbols` can start with integers. The OP's code even contains a `Symbol` that starts with an integer: `:"589d62c016bd4d0005bccc15"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in Ruby `:589d62c016bd4d0005bccc15` is not a valid Symbol literal. If you have a string starting from integers or integer itself, converted to Symbol literal it will always have the following form:

```
'23'.to_sym
#=> :"23"
23.to_s.to_sym
#=> :"23"
```

Comment: like I have object ids that are unique alpha numeric. Do we have any such rules to define symbol literal?

Comment: @ArunG you can't have symbol starting with number in the notation you would expect (`:23`). Pretty much everything else will work.

Comment: so  :"23" is a valid symbol?

Comment: @ArunG sure it is. `:'23'.class` #=> `Symbol`

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Deineko

Comment: @ArunG please, make sure to accept the answer if that solved your problem.